# Em Spring MVC, como enviar uma informação para a view (.jsp) sem usar o ModelAndView?

Tags: java, aplicação-web, spring, spring-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web em Spring MVC.

Tenho um método que retorna uma lista (java.util.List) e preciso passar ela para a view (.jsp), porém sem atualizar a página.

Gostaria de saber alguma outra forma de passar as informações do Java para a view, porém sem usar o ModelAndView, pois quando o utilizo a página é atualizada.

Comment: Para que não haja um novo request, você terá que usar AJAX

Comment: Cria um Controller que receberá as requisições AJAX, e chamará os métodos que retornará os valores, então converta os valores para JSON, por exemplo, e devolve para o callback da sua função ajax processar e atualizar o html dinamicamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dito no comentário, você precisa de `Ajax` para evitar o carregamento da página.

Um exemplo utilizando Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/lista',
    success: function(data) {
         //Aqui você recebe sua lista
    }
});
```

Seu controller ficaria assim:

```
@ResponseBody//O spring vai retornar sua lista como texto, vai traduzir para Json
@RequestMapping(value = "/lista")
public List<Item> listagem() {
    //Aqui você retorna sua lista contendo os objetos
    return listaDao.findAll();
}
```